# Please make it more obvious when a post is migrated

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, notifications

In response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61585/why-are-all-of-my-posts-closed), I think we need to make it more obvious when a post has been migrated.

Here's an idea:

[image]

<sub><sub>Just ignore the part where balpha cleared this one up.</sub></sub>

Comment: All your post are belong to some other site.

Comment: Why limit to only the question asker? Anyone new to SOFU might bump into migrated questions.

Comment: Meanwhile, for question owners, the topbar message [has been implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282). Still then, I'd like the link to be more obvious (and maybe even [be moved upwards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73298/can-the-migrated-status-and-link-to-new-site-be-displayed-at-the-top-of-a-questio)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since December 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282), users will see a header message with the migration details, linking to both the original question and its new place. Like "*Your question ... was migrated to ...*":

[image: Migration notification on top of the screen]

Answer (score 13):

I recommend the following design instead:

[image: Migrated]

(Note: The siren should be animated in the actual implementation, preferably with a background sound loop of a ringing bell and the *"eee-ooo-eee-ooo"* type alarm).

Comment: I find your lack of freehand disturbing.

Comment: Woah, you have a steady hand!

Comment: +1 for the siren. I assume it would flash, right?

Comment: @squillman: Normally I would use freehand, but this isn't a bug report, it's supposed to represent how it would actually appear to users.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, it should flash, and the little light rays emanating from it should blink on and off.

Comment: The hand should be flipping you off.

Comment: @squillman: Now what kind of a way is that to treat someone who just wants to know why all his post are closed?  Certainly if all *my* post are closed and hand flip off, I am are very upset.

Comment: Just spreadin' the cheer :)

Comment: is that... clip art?

Comment: @squillman, the hand is towards the bottom right of that mockup.  It is clearly free of any interference; not attached to any arms or anything.  It's even got its own personal forcefield (highlighted in red for your convenience)!

Comment: @Andy: It's Google image search, which may or may not be clip art.

Answer (score 5):

> ### This question has been migrated to [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61585/13992) by [Welbog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog), [Double Welbog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443) and [Mega Welbog ♦♦♦](http://www.historyvortex.org/GodzillaGamePhoto3.jpg) Sep 31 at 23:41
>
> This question is a discussion of this website or community itself and is a better fit for [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 4):

I [suggest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63964/make-the-migrated-question-link-on-the-original-page-more-obvious) making the link itself simply more obvious:

[image: migrated to: shorturl of question]

Comment: Nice idea, but I wonder how much of the problem is people not realizing the link goes to their post and how much is them not seeing/bothering to look for the word "migrated" in the gray box in the first place.  (+1)

Comment: @Pop: hm, maybe "has been migrated and is now here:"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with the link thing, since there is a link directly to the question on the other site. But I agree that having a notification (and maybe also and activity on the recent page) might clear things up.

Comment: I think Jon is suggesting that the site name isn't obviously a link

Comment: I think Jon meant the link text, that's now “meta.stackoverflow.com” and doesn't give a clue that it's a link to the new location of the question.

Comment: I think I meant that the link that... oh, nevermind :)

Comment: @Chris: To me, blue text is obviously a link, but where will it lead?

Comment: @Marcel - it's obvious to me too, but clearly not to everyone.

Comment: @Marcel - I think it only marginally looks link-ish, and, like you said, it's unclear that it goes to your question (in fact, wouldn't you think it just goes to the main meta site?)

Comment: @Jon B: I find it intuitive... "Your question was migrated to: Now click this link here to go there". Though, I can see what you mean.