# Make the migrated question link on the original page more obvious

Tags: feature-request, migration, usability

Just change the text to something like

> This question has been migrated to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/...
>   by: ...

(no separate notification as in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61594/please-make-it-more-obvious-when-a-post-is-migrated) request I mean)

---

**edit** example:

[image: modification of Andy E's Head's answer]

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that is pretty obvious in it's current format.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, clarification: I meant on the original page, so newcomers wouldn't be confused by the `migrated to meta.stackoverflow.com` -> "So, where exactly there?!"

Answer (score 1):

It would add a lot of extra bulk:

[image]

I think I prefer [Jon B's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61594/please-make-it-more-obvious-when-a-post-is-migrated), to be honest.

Comment: that's really huge. What about the shorthand notation (`/q/61585`, see my update)?

Comment: @Tobias: the shorthand looks better but there's still a chance of it being pushed down onto the next line.

Comment: For a fixed migrated-to site the shorthand would always have the same length as long as e.g. no 1k questions barrier is breached. But anyway, the main point is, the link-text should already indicate that it's not just a link to e.g. meta, but to the very migrated question