# Add a comment if migration is suggested, but question is then closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show comment when voting to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64275/show-comment-when-voting-to-migrate)

Sometimes when I vote to migrate a question, that question eventually gets closed as offtopic (because, say, 3 people said it was offtopic and 2 people wanted it migrated to Programmers).

This makes me sad, I do not like being listed as a person who voted to close as offtopic. I never did.

Suggestion:
**If a question gets closed, and there are votes for this question to be migrated, then automatically add a comment:**

> Hi username, some of us pesky closers believe you might be more lucky with your question on [this site of us]. Check it out!

Reasons for this would be:

1. Making me less sad.
2. Seamlessly guiding newcomers to a more appropriate site instead of scaring them away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show comment when voting to migrate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64275/show-comment-when-voting-to-migrate), [Why was this question closed as off-topic without being migrated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated)

Comment: God, how did you find those? I spent 10 minutes searching.

Comment: I cheated: they were in the "Related" sidebar. But that makes me think they were probably somewhere on the page as you composed the question. Lots of users seem to swear that the hits they get when writing a question are far better than those they get when trying to search. I've heard people even say that they start composing questions just as a search tactic. Such hasn't been my experience, but your luck may vary... :-)

Comment: @Cody, I definitely have better luck starting the question than searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they should do is **only list the closers that voted for the winning option**, so those of us that didn't vote for a crappy closing reason wouldn't be permanently affixed with the blame.

Answer (score 2):

My take on this is that if the question really *did* belong on that other site, it would have been migrated there by a general consensus. The fact that enough users did not agree with the migration seems to indicate that migration was not a good idea.

I frequently vote to close as generically "off-topic" (or even, "not a real question") despite the prior votes of other users to migrate a question to another site on the network. My reason for doing so is because I think that the question is a **bad question** and would not be a good fit for the other site.

[The golden rule of migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites/82986#82986) is not to migrate crap.

Sometimes, even though the *spirit* of a question would be better suited for another site, the *actual* question is not.

But if you really feel strongly that a question should be migrated, despite the votes that have been cast by other users, you can always flag it for moderator attention. They'll be able to assess whether the question is truly a good fit on the proposed site, and migrate it there if necessary, overriding whatever close votes may have been cast in the interim. Moderators can also migrate to any site in the network, including those for which migration paths are not unlocked (like Ask Ubuntu, for example).