# Can the migrated status and link to new site be displayed at the top of a question?

Tags: feature-request

I just saw the following [question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1797/why-is-my-question-closed) where someone asks why his question is closed.

Well looking on the [beginning](https://superuser.com/questions/223366/can-ping-ip-address-and-nslookup-hostname-but-cannot-ping-hostname-closed) of the referenced question, there is no hint, that it is migrated.
This problem can surly be reduced putting this information at the beginning.

Comment: As an aside: question owners are (soon) getting a notification [in the topbar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282). (Not just with the question itself, but on all pages, just like when one got a new badge.) Still then, moving up the migration message sounds like a good idea to me, especially when combined with something to [make it much more obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63964/make-the-migrated-question-link-on-the-original-page-more-obvious) that the link is clickable.

Answer (score 4):

> Well looking on the beginning of the referenced question there is no hint, that it is migrated.

Scrolling to the bottom of the question, the migration status is visible.

[image]

However, perhaps it is a good suggestion to have migration links at the top, similar to the way duplicates are handled.

[image]