# Reputation loss when a question is transferred

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, migration

I had asked a question on SuperUser which was then transferred to gaming.stackoverflow.com. I didnt have an account on this webpage and when I created the account for this sub-site, I wasn't gifted the rep for the upvotes on my transferred question.

TLDR;
Questions transferred dont give upvote reputation.

ALSO
My question was transferred to this other site, but this wasn't mentioned anywhere on SuperUser and I had to do a category search just to find it again. So having some sort of notification of a question being transferred would be good

Thanks

Comment: Usually taken care of by batch recalcs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rep wasn't properly recalculated - this has been done.

Also, we now inform a question owner about a migration; we'll be inserting a header message with the migration details, linking to both the original question and its new place. Like "*Your question ... was migrated to ...*":

[image: Migration notification on top of the screen]

Comment: Maybe also inform people who have stared a question that the question was moved as well? Since they stared it to get notifications...

Comment: Any details about those details? Many of us will never see it, but still curious!

Comment: @Arjan Probably something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73298/133693).  ok perhaps not - maybe similar to the "You have a new badge" messages ?

Comment: @Sathya, surely similar to the new badge message (I assume it's not just visible with the question itself, but on any page until closed). But still wondering about the text itself.

Comment: @Jarrod, I think the topbar notification makes [Please make it more obvious when a post is migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61594/please-make-it-more-obvious-when-a-post-is-migrated) to be `[status-completed]`? Feel free to post the example there ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Much appreciated!

Comment: You're informing the question owner, what about the people who've answered the question?