# "migrated from" info is too large

Tags: discussion, usability

I wonder if there's a need to have a note so **big** on migrated questions. Why is it any useful? If it is, can you make it smaller (it's too large, and just seems like a distraction to me), or even visible **only** to high-rep users? I say this last point because clicking on the note takes you to `page non-existent` if you are a mere mortal (the vast majority of SE users).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it any useful?

Because new users need to be made aware what happened to their question - especially now that there is an instant redirect to the target site. In my eyes, if anything, it is too *small!*

I can, however, see value in showing the info only to higher-rep users and the question's author. The latter is difficult to do, though, if the user doesn't have an account on the target site yet.

Comment: What value exactly? Making it harder to track a question's history?

Comment: @radp the fact that a question was migrated is relevant only to two groups of people: 1. The author, and 2. site users who need to decide whether the migration was justified. I can see the point of not shoving the info into everyone else's face, and hiding it in the actual history (although my general tendecy is that if in doubt, show it, and in big letters)

Comment: Given the recently introduced [topbar notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282), I don't see any added value for the original question asker. It might still help folks getting to learn how the sites work, but then I agree that it could be much smaller.