# What happens to migrated favorites?

Tags: discussion, migration, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

Before I do my own investigation and/or testing, does anyone know off the top of their head what happens, for instance, if a question I marked as favorite on stack overflow is migrated to, say, programmers.se?

- Is it favorite'd in my account at the new location?
- Am I still notified on SO of changes to the question at the new site?
- Am I notified of the migration, since technically the favorite did change on SO?
- Is the favorite removed on the old site?

Comment: I think this will be [status-declined] on account of you don't always have an account on the other site (which I think would be a trivial thing for them to implement [add current profile to new site on transfer of question if it does not exist], but I'm not sure about the logistics and ramifications of that implementation)

Comment: @dra this isn't a feature request, it's just an attempt to find out what the current situation is.  It may lead to some feature requests, but right now I'm seeking to understand, hopefully without having to experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it favorite'd in my account at the new location?

I don't believe so. I suspect this would be too expensive an operation for a very popular question, so it's probably not done.

> Am I still notified on SO of changes to the question at the new site?

Given the above, no. If I'm mistaken, then it would depend on your notification settings on the target site, and you'd get notified through the global inbox as applicable.

> Am I notified of the migration, since technically the favorite did change on SO?

As a post author, we do get [notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282) when our questions get migrated, but I'm pretty sure there aren't notifications for that kind of action as a favourite.

> Is the favorite removed on the old site?

No. None of the moderation actions (that I know of) affect the favourite votes at all, because the voting state has to be preserved through all of the question states, including a delete/undelete cycle.

Comment: I think there is a recent change that now alerts us when our own questions get specifically migrated. Don't know how it'll impact *favorites*, but in terms of your own questions, I think that was some feature that was recently added.

Comment: @Grace: Okay, I must have missed that. Even so, we had fought hard for that kind of notification, so a favourite notification of that type probably wouldn't have been implemented. I could be wrong.

Comment: No longer surprised about this, after I did some digging to find out if I was dreaming or not. [Found it in the RFC linking to this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/reputation-loss-when-a-question-is-transferred/73282#73282) - it was relatively un-announced and it's on a question addressing something else entirely. It did include a comment suggesting "Can this happen for favorites?", though.

Comment: Good find! Updated. Thanks, @Grace.