# Migrate favorites along with questions

Tags: feature-request, migration, bookmarks

A question was asked on Stack Overflow. [Are password reset links that don't expire a security risk?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24260/3290)

I marked it as a favourite, because I thought it was interesting. I also voted it +1. Then I flagged it for migration to IT Security. When it arrived here, I marked it as a favourite again, and voted it +1 again.

Surely it should have already been marked as a favourite, and should have already had a vote from me locked in? I already have accounts on SO and on ITSec.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that favourites get cleared - not sure on votes. I'll have a scout round meta.SO to see if there is an answer there

Comment: I think down votes are removed. Upvotes stay, as we can see on question migrated from StackOverflow, with often have a very high number of votes on poor answers.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78200/what-happens-to-migrated-favorites