# Better alerts in network inbox

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Currently, you only get alerts in your inbox if someone replies to your question, leaves a comment, or you get a chat message (and probably a couple more that I'm missing).

It would be nice if you got alerted in the inbox for the following events:

- question/answer gets edited
- question/answer gets deleted
- question gets closed
- question gets migrated

This way we can get more transparency on what happens to our stuff without having to go to each site/question individually.

Answer (score 5):

Notifications for

> question/answer gets edited

would provoke edit wars. Notifications for

> question/answer gets deleted
>
> question gets closed
>
> question gets migrated

would cause people to complain too much about community and / or moderator actions.

(Not necessarily my opinions, but these are the types of reasons that have been given before for declining similar requests)

Answer (score 2):

**I imagine that you don't get network-wide notifications for these events because they shouldn't be all that common.** If your questions/answers are getting deleted, closed, or migrated frequently, you probably have other problems.

Likewise, I don't see the need for a network-wide notification of edits. If the editing system is working properly, *each edit should be an improvement on your post that doesn't require your immediate response.* In fact, network-wide edit notifications could actually be *detrimental* by triggering an "edit war" whenever a post is modified.

Answer (score 0):

> question gets migrated

Note that this will [already generate a notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61594/please-make-it-more-obvious-when-a-post-is-migrated) *on the site the question was migrated from*. Not in your inbox, but as a banner, which you might see if, say, you were to go looking for the question.

Obviously if your question gets migrated, closed, deleted or edited and then commented on or *answered*, you'll get inbox notifications for *that*... So if the person editing, migrating, closing or deleting feels you need to be pulled in from any site on the network, they can always just leave a comment.

Comment: If a comment or answer is posted, then the question is deleted, unless you're 10k+ any notification would be useless as you wouldn't be able to see the comment / answer.

Comment: @agf: well, it'll take you to a page that tells you your question has been deleted... ;-P